# imagePickerController set UIImageView.image does not change the image displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to set the UIImageView's image as the return of UIImagePickerController below. My UIImageView profileImageView is instantiated in viewdidload. Strangely, the UIImagePickerController returned image has not been displayed in profileImageView. Initially I thought it was the image issue, so I fixed it to SR-rewards.jpg. Adding NSLog, it shows [profileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SR-rewards.jpg"]] has been executed, but profileImageView.image.size.height is 0. 
Then I give it another shoot using    
`[profileImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject: [UIImage imageNamed:@"SR-rewards.jpg"] waitUntilDone:YES];`
to run it in the main thread. Though, the image is still not displayed, profileImageView.image.size.height changes to 277.

Any idea for the cause? And how can I set the image?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [profileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SR-rewards.jpg"]];//[self cropImage:smallImage];
    NSLog(@"%f" , profileImageView.image.size.height);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Regards
Hammer

Comment: seems your profileImageVIEW IS NIL. check it using breakpoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update UI in the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [profileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SR-rewards.jpg"]];
});
```